# Accumulate rows of NumPy array based on the last column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cumsum, accumulate

I have the following question. I have an array with coordinate arrays in it, the first three entries are the x,y,z coordinate, the 4th entry is the id of the track. I want to add a drift to the tracks, which starts after the first time point. Is there a simple approach of adding the drift dynamically to the tracks with their ids, which could have different length, instantly to the whole array? (So as you can see, the track with id has only 3 coordinate entries, and track with id 3 has 6)

```
import numpy as np
drift=np.array([1,1,0])
a = np.array([[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],
              [1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,3],
              [1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,3],
              [1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,3]])
```

**Output:**

```
output = np.array([[1,1,1,0],[2,2,1,0],[3,3,1,0],
                   [1,1,1,2],[2,2,1,2],[1,1,1,3],
                   [2,2,1,3],[3,3,1,3],[4,4,1,3],
                   [5,5,1,3],[6,6,1,3]])
```

Comment: What is track with ids and track without? Can you please add more description. What did you try so far? What is your approach? I just want to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be done in a vectorized manner:

```
import numpy as np


drift = np.array([1, 1, 0])
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 2], 
              [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 3], 
              [1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 3]])


def multirange(counts: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Calculates concatenated ranges. Code was taken at:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027936/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-many-arange-calls-in-numpy
    """
    counts = counts[counts != 0]
    counts1 = counts[:-1]
    reset_index = np.cumsum(counts1)
    incr = np.ones(counts.sum(), dtype=int)
    incr[0] = 0
    incr[reset_index] = 1 - counts1
    incr.cumsum(out=incr)
    return incr


def drifts(ids: np.ndarray,
           drift: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    diffs = np.diff(ids)
    max_drifts_per_id = np.concatenate((np.where(diffs)[0], [len(ids) - 1])) + 1
    max_drifts_per_id[1:] = max_drifts_per_id[1:] - max_drifts_per_id[:-1]
    multipliers = multirange(max_drifts_per_id)
    drifts = np.tile(drift, (len(ids), 1))
    return drifts * multipliers[:, np.newaxis]


a[:, :-1] += drifts(a[:, -1], drift)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 3],
       [1, 1, 0, 3],
       [2, 2, 0, 3],
       [3, 3, 0, 3],
       [4, 4, 0, 3],
       [5, 5, 0, 3]])
```

---

**Explanation**:

The idea of the `drifts` function is to take an array of ids (which in our case we can obtain as   `a[:, -1]`: `array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])`) and `drift` (`np.array([1, 1, 0])`) to get the following array which then can be appended to the original array:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [4, 4, 0],
       [5, 5, 0]])
```

---

**Line by line:**

```
diffs = np.diff(ids)
```

Here we get an array where all non-zero elements will have indices of the last ids in the first array:

```
array([0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

See [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) for details.

---

```
max_drifts_per_id = np.concatenate((np.where(diffs)[0], [len(ids) - 1])) + 1
```

`np.where(diffs)[0]` will give indices of those non-zero elements from the previous array. We append index of the last element and increment the resulting indices by 1 in order to get ranges later. See [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for details. After concatenation `max_drifts_per_id` will be:

```
array([ 3,  5, 11])
```

---

```
max_drifts_per_id[1:] = max_drifts_per_id[1:] - max_drifts_per_id[:-1]
```

Here from the previous result we get an array of end values of ranges:

```
array([3, 2, 6])
```

---

```
multipliers = multirange(max_drifts_per_id)
```

We use `multirange` as an efficient alternative to concatenating calls of [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). See [How to efficiently concatenate many arange calls in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027936/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-many-arange-calls-in-numpy)
 for details. Resulting `multipliers` will be:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

---

```
drifts = np.tile(drift, (len(ids), 1))
```

By [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) we expand the `drift` to have the same number of rows as `ids`:

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

---

```
return drifts * multipliers[:, np.newaxis]
```

We multiply it by `multipliers` and get:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [4, 4, 0],
       [5, 5, 0]])
```

---

And finally this returned value can be added to the original array:

```
a[:, :-1] += drifts(a[:, -1], drift)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin way of doing this as far as I know, but you can solve it with this simple loop:

```
import numpy as np
drift=np.array([1,1,0])
a = np.array([[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],
[1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,3]])

_id = 0
n = 0
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    if a[i, 3] == _id:
        a[i, 0:3] = a[i, 0:3] + n * drift
        n += 1
    else:
        _id = a[i, 3]
        n = 1

print(a)
```